# Why am I not getting an error when reseting a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

In the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x=4;
    int y=5;
    cout << x <<endl;
    int& foo = x;

    // foo is now a reference to x so this sets x to 56
    foo = 56; //reseting the reference foo
    cout << x <<endl;
    cout << foo <<endl;


    foo= y; //this is supposed to be forbidden 
    cout << foo <<endl; // but I am getting foo=5

return 1;
}
```

This is compiling fine and I get `foo=5` in the last `cout`. For what I've read  you cannot reseat a reference to make it refer to a different object, so I was expecting an error, what is going here?

Comment: It's not reassigning the reference, it's assigning the value of y to x.

Comment: @Frank I thought "reseting a reference" meant changing its value, since I've read you can't only initialize a reference once, at declaration time., What would be an example of reseting a reference (that would generate an error), then?

Comment: There's no example because you can't do it. If for instance you had a class which had a member reference, you would get an error about being unable to have a default `operator=` because a reference can't be changed.

Comment: References are not objects. They are... well... references to other objects. References don't even really "exist" as far as the C++ abstract machine is concerned (though this is an oversimplification). For example, if you do `&foo` you are not getting the address of `foo`, but of the object `foo` refers to.

Comment: Look up *reseating reference c++", and not the spelling.

Comment: In https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs , How can you reseat a reference to make it refer to a different object?   they say no way... So i was trying to construct an example to illustrate this. I still don't see why my example is not was I was expecting.

Comment: @ Thomas Matthews I just realized that, but still don't see the difference between reset and reseat.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver There simply is no syntax for resetting/reseating/reassigning/rebinding references. You cannot generate an error for it because there simply is no way to write code that would try to do it. References can only be bound to a variable at their initialization, which is a different syntax construct than assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a reference has been created, any attempt to use the reference variable is equivalent to using the object that was assigned to it.

So when we look at the following line of code:

```
foo= y; //this is suppose to be forbidden
```

We see that it does not attempt to re-assign the reference, it assigns the value of `y` to the object referred to by `foo`.

> What would be an example of reseting a reference (that would generate an error), then?

While **we** can't write code that reassigns references, the compiler can end up in situations where it would have to emit code that is the equivalent of that when dealing with references embedded within other data structures. And it's still illegal for the compiler to do so.

For example, the following will fail to compile because the compiler-generated assignement operator for `X` cannot be created since it would involve reassigning `ref`.

```
struct X {
  int& ref;
};

void foo() {
  int v1 = 1;
  int v2 = 2;

  X x1{v1};
  X x2{v2};

  x1 = x2; // Boom!
}
```

**Edit:** Answering the followup question here because it's extremely relevant.

Now you may wonder: "Hey! if the reference behaves as a proxy for another variable, why can't the compiler just use that logic to generate a valid assignment operator for `struct X`?"

Well, not really. The underlying expectation here is that once i do `var_a = var_b`, then *by default*, `var_a` is now effectively the same as `var_b`.

So if `x1.ref` points to `v1` and `x2.ref` points to `v2`, then the expectation is that *by default*, `x1 = x2` would lead to `x1.ref` pointing to `v2`.

Doing anything else would just lead to confusion and surprises in the long run.

Comment: I am not sure what "reassigning ref" means, so in the last line we are assigning the value of x2 to x1, what does it has to do with the reference ref and why is it an error?

Comment: @juan, `X` has a reference member. So assigning a `X` to another `X` would involve reseating the reference (because we certainly don't want that operation to assign `v2` to `v1`).

Comment: Isn't assigning v2 to v1  in your example, equivalent to  doing foo= y in mine, that is copying the value of v2 to v1?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver That's a very good question (assuming you meant assigning x2 to x1). The idea is that the behavior you are describing would lead to too many "suprises", and if that's what you want, you can always explicitely implement  `X::operator=()` to make it behave this way, so it's better that the compiler forces you to be explicit in these scenarios.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver does this help: a reference is not a variable. It is an alias to, another name for, an existing variable. It doesn't refer to or point to a variable. It IS that variable.